# By the ease with which

Tags: meaning

> As a result, we have a math curriculum with no historical perspective or thematic coherence, a fragmented collection of assorted topics and techniques, united only by the ease with which they can be reduced to step-by-step procedures.

What does the author mean by "united only by the ease with which they can be reduced to step-by-step procedures"?

Comment: See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing the "assorted topics" have in common is that they can all easily be "reduced to step-by-step procedures".